# jQuery Mobile refresh page onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm making an application with jquery Mobile, is there any way , when i click a button link page , it also refresh the page (#page_aboutus). Thank you

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
  <li data-theme="c"><a href="#page_aboutus" onclick=""><small>About Us</small></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? Reload the whole framework? Or just the current page? Are you using single page or multi page model?

Comment: no, i mean just the current page, i'm using multi page model.

Comment: It depends what you want to do, what kind of elements you have in that page. Reloading a page div in multi-page model isn't possible. Unless you have a clone of that page, inject it again and remove old copy. If you have forms, it's easier to refresh it, all you need is to reset forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
onclick="window.reload()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Reloading a page div in multi-page model will be very tough because it will break the entire application DOM. in case you want to trigger a method or to apply some mobile look and feel, try reloading the element with refresh functionality of that element.
have a look on page reload functionality with page container widgets. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load